# How do I add Wireless Diagnostics to Launchpad?

Tags: terminal, wifi, applications, launchpad

In macOS, if I Option+Click the wireless network icon on the top right of the screen, there is a button for "Open Wireless Diagnostics...". I find this tool quite useful, not useful enough to pin to the dock, but useful enough that I'd like to be able to access it easier from Launchpad. In particular, I am interested in it opening the Scan window which lists detailed information about wireless networks.

Is there a way that I can add this tool to Launchpad? Is there a .app that I can copy to the Applications folder? Or maybe there is a terminal command that will open this tool, and I can make a .app that just runs that terminal command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a symlink that's visible in the Launchpad.

The path to Wireless Diagnostics is **/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Wireless Diagnostics.app**

Start dragging the app using a mouse, hold ⌘ and ⌥ keys, then drop it in either **/Applications** or **~/Applications**.